# How to POST JSON on Google Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps, google-chrome-app

How to webrequest POST JSON on Google Chrome App? Kindly also give an example since I am a newbie for Google Chrome App.

If this is a duplicate quest, please comment the answer link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object, the same at that in AJAX. Please take a look at the reference [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)

Here's an example from w3c.org:

```
function log(message) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // in case of network errors this might not give reliable results
    if(this.readyState == this.DONE)
      console.log("log entry sent with status: " + this.status);
  }
  client.open("POST", chrome.extension.getURL("/log"), true);
  client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
  client.send(message);
}
```